# From blob to filesystem. Which is the best location to store images?

Tags: mysql, image, git, svn, backup

I have read a lot of discussions about this topic and we all agree that, in most cases, the best solution is to save the images on the filesystem, and record the path in the database.
For this reason, we are redesigning our web application and enjoy all the advantages of this type of solution.

My question however is:
what is the best location where to save the images, especially to avoid problems of version control and deploying? The same way as the database, I think it's better that these files are not under version control, right?

For this I would like to get an advice on what is the best location where to save the file system:

- Inside the Working Copy saying to version control to ignore them?
- Outside the working copy?
- In the folder where the database stores the data so you have "all the data together"?

are 3000 images of about 2mb
the control version is svn but soon will migrate to git
the db is MySQL with InnoDB tables with innodb_file_per_table

Comment: What OS platform?  Are you using a shared file server?

Comment: To bad filesystem doesn't respect database rollbacks so you could end up have phantom files on your filesystem.

Comment: has CentOs 5.x, no shared file server

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for your comment but we already know pros and cons of this kind of solution